# PySide Dialog for files

Tags: python, pyside

I want to have the chance to choose a file or a directory, just one not both.  For linux and OSX, I have the following code working:

```
dialog = QFileDialog(self)
dialog.setFileMode(QFileDialog.AnyFile)
dialog.setViewMode(QFileDialog.Detail)
```

But, on other computer, where I had installed Windows 7. It doesnot work at same. No idea. Actually, with code above, I can just choose a file, not a directory.

Any suggestion?

Comment: What do you mean `On Windows I couldn't be able to get it. `? It didn't work? What is `path_home`?

Comment: I'd rewrited the question.